# Copy entire row to the next empty row in another worksheet which begins from specific row

Tags: excel, vba, forms, copy-paste

I have tried to search for an answer in this forum, I´ve also tried to modify the code to suit my requirement but still without success. Could someone please help me?

I have an excel document with 6 sheets. **All sheets have an identical (fixed) form**. First 5 sheets are basically databases where I have electrical parts from 5 different projects, and 6th Sheet is an empty form, which should be used as an order list.

What I need is a code that will copy the entire row from sheet 1/2/3/4/5 to the Sheet 6 if the criteria is met. The criteria is an entered quantity (different from 0) in column C (Sheets 1/2/3/4/5). That what is the main problem, I need to copy entire row to the next empty row in Sheet 6 – but form begins from the row 14 (A14), above is a header.

Now I have code for command button which works only if I am working in one sheet and trying to copy rows to Sheet 6 (Order list). 
If I am working in Sheet 5 and I jump for example to Sheet 3, and if I try to add some more parts to order list from Sheet 3, it will just copy all over the existing parts in order list, which I already copied from Sheet 5.

Here is the code which I have so far (in this example I used only Sheet 5 - "Gemeinsam"):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    a = Worksheets("Gemeinsam").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    b = 14
    For i = 14 To a

       If Worksheets("Gemeinsam").Cells(i, 3).Value > 0 Then

          Worksheets("Gemeinsam").Rows(i).Copy
          Worksheets("Stückliste").Activate
          Worksheets("Stückliste").Cells(b, 1).Select
          ActiveSheet.Paste
          Worksheets("Gemeinsam").Activate
       b = b + 1
       End If
    Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gemeinsam").Cells(14, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello DaniloS, i'm not actually sure what is your goal here. You said you need to copy one row from every sheet with matching criteria. Where would the criteria be? In column C is only 1 row that will match the criteria you are looking for?

Comment: So your criteria is >0, and for each sheet, 1 to 5, you want to check each cell to the last row, and if the cell contains a value >0, then copy the row and paste to the first empty row in sheet6. right?

Comment: Do you only have the 6 woksheets?

Comment: Hello @Damian
It is foreseen to "manually" move through the Excel sheets, for example: in sheet 4 I found 5 el. parts which I want to order -> I will put the amount into column C -> click on the button to add those rows to sheet 6 where I have "Order list". Than I go for example to sheet 2 and there I will choose 7 el. parts also with puting amount into the column C, and than again click on the button to add entire row to "order list" (Sheet 6).

Comment: Hello @GMalc, 
no, I dont do check at the same time. I just go through the excel sheets and first search for the parts which I need to order and than I enter value in column C.
And yes, I only have 6 sheets

Comment: How you prepare your worksheet was not the question; when you are ready to click the button is the process identified in the comment, what you were asking to do. was the point of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you only have the 6 worksheets in the workbook.  Some of the variable names have been changed, but hopefully understood.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim DestLastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Stückliste")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Stückliste" Then
            LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 14 To LastRow
                If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value > 0 Then
                    DestLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    ws.Rows(i).Copy ws1.Rows(DestLastRow)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the first `DestLastRow` it just needs to be within the For statement. The only reason i mentioned it is that i was going to suggest the same code, except i prefer to use `Filter` and `SpecialCells`. Also, `ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row` should be a 1 not 5

Comment: @GMalc True, but if it is removed, the second one would have to be moved above the copy,paste line otherwise the first copy/paste will fail

Comment: If you place the DestLastRow above the previous line, then you don't need the line in the beginning. Also, you need to add +1 or else you will be rewriting over the last used row.

Comment: @GMalc Edited to eliminate redundant variable declaration

Comment: Thank you @Darrell H,
I will try it tomorrow when I get to work.
I am not 100% sure, but if I can to attach my exel file here, I would gladly do that, so you can better understand what is my question.

Comment: Hello @Darrell H,
I´ve tried your code, but sadly it doesn´t works. Somehow it is copied into the header of the order list (not to / from row 14, but to row 11).
Here are the screenshots:
http://imgur.com/E6mtjNh
http://imgur.com/GtaCV9w

Comment: @DaniloS Ah yes, you are using three rows for your header and only populating the top one.  I would use one and make the row size bigger.  The other option is to move the populated cell in the header to the bottom (row 13).  I also added a plus one to the `DestLastRow`.  Part of automating tasks successfully is designing sheets that allow for repeatable actions to be taken.  You may have to modify the code to suit, but the concept of looping and pasting should be absorbed here.

Comment: @Darrell H Thank you very much for prompt answer. I will try / modify your edited code now.
Yes, I know what you are meaning, the problem is that I am not the one who was defined this form. It is form which suits to import in SAP system in my company. That basically means that I have not to much space to play around. :)

Comment: @Darrell H I think I have the solution! I will just insert word "DRAFT" into 13. row (no matter wich cell - in my / your code it was cell (13,5), but I can modify that).
Than, when I have filled order list, I would add one more command button - to which I would click and create new FINAL ORDER Sheet / Table, in which would be automatically deleted word DRAFT from row 13 and just copied all filled el. parts. Thant means - I need to search now for code to creating new sheet or table. :)
Thank you a lot for your spent time and for an ingenious and simple solution!